# what is the exact use of MMRecord and MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, magicalrecord, mmrecord

I need to know what is the exact use of MMRecord and MagicalRecord, if anyone has the idea about this please share me with example and usage?

Comment: check this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-core-data-fetching-with-magical-record--mobile-13680 2)https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord

Comment: Thanks, @Jigar and do you know any tutorials for MMRecord rather than Github

Comment: Check this link http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @sasquatch